# Having trouble setting up expo react app project

Tags: git, expo, create-react-app

I am fairly new to react native and can't seem to figure out what am I doing wrong here. I have everything installed as required by the official documentation (node , npm , git) but I keep getting this error.

[image]

I even tried copying the git folder and pasting it there but it gave me another error. Unistalled node and reinstalled it still nothing